# How to disable drag highlight on a QTreeWidget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTreeWidget` where I reimplemented the `mousePressEvent` to only highlight the current item selected.

However if you press it and drag the mouse, it selects all of them.

How can I disable this? `QTreeWidget` doesn't have a `mouseDragEvent` to reimplement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the selection mode to a "*single selection*".

```
QTreeWidget* tree = new QTreeWidget;
tree->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything. When I click one column, it only highlights that one, but if I click it and drag sideways, it highlights the entire row.

Comment: If you want to have just a single cell selected, call also `tree->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);`

Comment: Ok thanks! now it works, however I can drag it to the next cell and it will select that cell. I suppose I must reimplement mouseMoveEvent as well?

Comment: Yes, you have to reimplement the *mouseMoveEvent*. But maybe an empty implementation would be enough. The default QAbstractItemView::mouseMoveEvent() handles just selection.